# Ssh from Ubuntu to Windows 7

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, windows-7

I was just about to try sshing for the first time and before I get into it, I want to know what's the best way to go about it. In particular, I'm currently running Linux through crouton on an HP chromebook and I want to ssh into and old windows 7 pc. Ideally I would love to have some sort of bash shell inside the windows ssh as I'm not so confident with cmd but I can make do. Are there any packages/apps that I should install on my old pc before I start trying. Preferably if there was something like WSL but for windows 7 that'd be great but I can't seem to find anything like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no ssh daemon (service) for windows from Microsoft.
So installing shell on windows, it is only about run it locally.

To connect with ssh on remote windows, you should install 3rd party ssh server on windows.